# Is Gerard 't Hooft's Cellular Automaton Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics background independent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, coordinate-systems, determinism, cellular-automaton

In Gerard 't Hooft in his Cellular Automata Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics

(https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262145006_The_Cellular_Automaton_Interpretation_of_Quantum_Mechanics_A_View_on_the_Quantum_Nature_of_our_Universe_Compulsory_or_Impossible)

he concludes:

> It may seem odd that our theory, unlike most other approaches, does not contain any
>   strange kinds of stochastic differential equation, no “quantum logic”, not an infinity of
>   other universes, no pilot wave, just completely ordinary equations of motion that we
>   have hardly been able to specify, as they could be almost anything.

Does this mean that 't Hooft's Interpretation is background independent? Can it be applied to any coordinate system?

Also, since he says "they could be almost anything" does it mean that his hypothesis is unfalsifiable? Does this mean that 't Hooft considers that all cellular automata models exist as universes?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20860/109928, with an answer by ['t Hooft himself](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/34436/109928)

Comment: @StéphaneRollandin He concludes with a "do not believe in no-go theorems". Does this imply that he proposes that all his cellular automata models are possible? In that case, does he believe that all his cellular automata models exist on some kind of "multiverse"?